# mySQLi query for a specific month and date and year

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using mySQl browser to test a specific query that does not seem to wish to work. I wish to pull data on specific year, day, month but not all three at once. for example my database is dated back to 1982 and i wish to pull the most called value of number1 in the month of april. Below is my current query

```
SELECT number1, COUNT(number1) most FROM draws GROUP BY number1 WHERE MONTH(Date) = 4 ORDER BY most DESC;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  That way is hard to help you.  Post the table structure, the expected result, and more info.  What in the world is mySQl browser?

Comment: I have no idea how to post a table but table name is draws. columns are id, date, number1, number2, number3, number4.....

I wish to pull the most common values from number1 ( highest to lowest) for the month of april for all time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is invalid, group by can NOT be before Where

```
SELECT number1, COUNT(number1) most 
FROM draws 
WHERE substr(Date, 6,2) = '04' 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

assuming your Date is a date or datetime or timestamp type
What's the points to select and count on the same column?

Comment: This worked but I would have to check it with a smaller database. Thanks you also for correcting me and letting me know what I did wrong. Sorry date was done by yyyy-mm-dd format.